# Cocoa pod Installation issue

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install GoogleMaps framework through cocoa pods. But I am getting following error when trying to install. Can anyone help me to sort out this issue.

$ pod try GoogleMaps

Updating spec repositories

Performing a deep fetch of the `master` specs repo to improve future performance
[!] /usr/local/bin/git fetch --unshallow

error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

Comment: have u install cocoapods by - 

sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: Yes, I have installed the cocoa pods by the above command and I got the response as 1 gem installed. After that I tried with "pod try GoogleMaps" as mentioned in the Google Map doc.

Comment: Have you tried other pods?  I just ran "pod try GoogleMaps" here and it ran just fine.

Comment: try this - sudo gem update cocoapods